# Korn Shell Script on Linux Red Hat

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

My default shell is Bash and I am on directory /opt/app/IRMS and execute a script /opt/app/depl/bin/runjob.sh. Runall exists and is a soft link.

I get the following error :

```
[tidal@atlesapp002 IRMS]$ ksh -x /opt/app/depl/bin/runjob.sh execute
ls irms_inq.env
    + myenv=irms_inq.env
    + . ./irms_inq.env
    + . /home/tidal/cfg/setenv
    + export PATH
    + export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    + export FPATH
    + export SQLPATH
    + PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.
    + . /home/tidal/cfg/python.env
    + PY=/opt/python
    + PATH=/opt/python/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.
    + LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/opt/python/lib
    + . /home/tidal/cfg/svn.env
    + SVN=/opt/app/svn
    + PATH=/opt/app/svn/bin:/opt/python/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.
    + LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/svn/lib::/opt/python/lib
    + . /home/tidal/cfg/ora.env
    + CLI=/opt/app/instantclient_11_2
    + NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
    + export NLS_LANG
    + LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/instantclient_11_2:/opt/app/svn/lib::/opt/python/lib
    + export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    + TNS_ADMIN=/opt/app/instantclient_11_2
    + export TNS_ADMIN
    + PATH=/opt/app/svn/bin:/opt/python/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.:/opt/app/instantclient_11_2
    + export PATH
    + . /home/tidal/cfg/depl.env
    + DEPL=/opt/app/depl
    + PATH=/opt/app/svn/bin:/opt/python/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.:/opt/app/instantclient_11_2:/opt/app/depl/bin
    + FPATH=:/opt/app/depl/lib
    + SQLPATH=:/opt/app/depl/lib
    + . /home/tidal/cfg/putils.env
    + PATH=/opt/app/svn/bin:/opt/python/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.:/opt/app/instantclient_11_2:/opt/app/depl/bin:/opt/app/putils/bin
    + SQLPATH=:/opt/app/depl/lib:/opt/app/putils/lib
    + pwd
    + irmspwd=/opt/app/IRMS
    + PATH=/opt/app/svn/bin:/opt/python/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tidal/bin:.:/opt/app/instantclient_11_2:/opt/app/depl/bin:/opt/app/putils/bin:/opt/app/IRMS/bin
    + SQLPATH=:/opt/app/depl/lib:/opt/app/putils/lib:/opt/app/IRMS/lib
    + SQLPATH=:/opt/app/depl/lib:/opt/app/putils/lib:/opt/app/IRMS/lib:/opt/app/IRMS/src
    + runall execute

/opt/app/depl/bin/runjob.sh[7]: runall: not found [No such file or directory]
[tidal@atlesapp002 IRMS]$
====

    [tidal@atlesapp002 bin]$ ls -al
    total 96

        drwxrwxr-x 3 tidal tidal 4096 Jun  9 13:29 .
        drwxrwxr-x 4 tidal tidal 4096 May 19 16:38 ..
            lrwxrwxrwx 1 tidal tidal    8 Jun  8 12:56 runall -> setup.sh
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal 2319 May 19 16:38 runall.save
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal  831 May 19 16:38 runcp.sh
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal   54 Jun  9 13:29 runjob.sh
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal 2242 May 19 16:38 runsockets.pl
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 tidal tidal    9 Jun  9 00:01 runsql -> runsql.sh
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal 1877 May 19 16:38 runsql.save
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal 1877 May 19 16:38 runsql.sh
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal 5590 May 19 16:38 setParm.pl
        -rwxr-xr-x 1 tidal tidal 2319 May 19 16:38 setup.sh
```

Comment: What is the first/shebang (`#!`) line of the `setup.sh` script? Does it refer to a file that exists?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `runall` started from $PATH and not from current directory `./runall`, since /opt/app/IRMS/bin was added to the $PATH.
Try the following:

1. start ksh `[tidal@atlesapp002 IRMS]$ ksh`
2. run `/opt/app/depl/bin/runjob.sh execute`

   If this does not help try adding /opt/app/IRMS/bin to PATH and then export PATH

Answer (score 0):

Yes when I added ksh to the runall script it worked.

like ksh runall

Why ?